# Debian's Wordpress with broken plugin path?

Tags: debian, wordpress

I've installed an Wordpress from Debian Wheezy package system and the plugins folder appears to be broken.

As stated in the error log files of Apache2:

```
[error] File does not exist: /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/var
```

The plugins are looking for an URL based on the full path, and not on the relative path. I can "temporary fix" the problem making a symbolic link to /var on the plugins folder, but I know that this is wrong and dirty.

I don't know where to start debugging this. So any help is welcome.

Additional information:
/etc/wordpress/htaccess

```
# Multisites generated htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Apache2 Configuration File:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Alias /wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content
DocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress

ServerAdmin cc@if.ufrj.br

<Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
DirectoryIndex index.php
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content>
Options FollowSymLinks
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

The problem was in the file:
/etc/wordpress/config-myblog.com.php

The line:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/srv/www/wp-content/myblog.com');
```

Should be:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/lib/wordpress/wp-content');
```

It's strange because the first directory is just a symlink to the second one, since I'm only hosting one blog in this machine. But this solves the problem.